# rxjava: retryWhen doesn't work in my code?

Tags: rx-java

My code is like this :

The output is :

```
It just come in

number is: 6

Boo!
```

My expectation is if the exception is FooException, it should resubscribe, however, it looks like just subscribe once.

I don't know what's wrong with my code.

One more question,how can set maximum retry(for example, even return FooException, I just want to resubscribe twice)

```
     public class ErrorEmitter implements Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer> {
    private int throwAnErrorCounter = 7;
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {

        System.out.println("It just come in");
        if (throwAnErrorCounter > 4) {
            throwAnErrorCounter--;
            System.out.println("number is: "+throwAnErrorCounter);
            subscriber.onError(new FooException());
            return;
        }
        if (throwAnErrorCounter > 0) {
            throwAnErrorCounter--;
            System.out.println("number is: "+throwAnErrorCounter);
            subscriber.onError(new BooException());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("number is will complete");
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
}



        Observable.create(new ErrorEmitter()).retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>() {
        public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> attempts) {
            return attempts.flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
                                        public Observable<?> call(Throwable error) {
                                            if (error instanceof FooException) {
                                                return Observable.timer(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                                            }
                                            return Observable.error(error);
                                        }
                                    }
            );
        }
    }).subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("complete");
        }

        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
        }

        public void onNext(Integer integer) {

            System.out.println("it is in next ");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Try to replace the `timer` with `Observable.just(null)` and see if you can find out what goes wrong.